# NOKIA S40 Development

Tags: java-me, csv, nokia

please give me a sample code for read/write CSV file in nokia S40 application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are open source libraries for parsing CSV files, but I don't think any of them work on Java ME. However the CSV format is pretty simple to parse, as shown in [Parsing CSV file in J2ME](http://hany.ishabab.com/j2me/parsing-csv-file-in-j2me/).